# Run (CTRL + F11) dont work on xml files on Eclipse bundle with Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

I've downloaded adt-bundle-windows-x86_64. Everything work fine but if I'm focused on a xml file when I click on Run button or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> or try to run from the Menu, it doesn't work.

This is a special configuration in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch
>   Operation -> Always Launch the previously launched application

Or you can use Select a .java file via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> then Run the project's exec via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

I see all above ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900235/eclipse-make-ctrlf11-launch-android-project-even-when-on-xml-file).